# How to create a Source in Akka with Actor to serve WebSocket connection

Tags: scala, websocket, akka

I try to create a simple chat with Akka Actors, Streams, and WebSockets. I want to create separate Sink and Source to [serve](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/server-side/websocket-support.html#handling-messages) WebSocket connection.

I create a chat room per `roomId`:

```
path("ws" / "room" / IntNumber) { roomId => {
  println(s"Connecting to room $roomId")
  parameter("userName") { userName =>
    extractUpgradeToWebSocket { upgrade =>
      val chatRoom = ChatRooms.findOrCreate(roomId)
      val (sink, source) = chatRoom.getSinkAndSource(userName)
      complete(upgrade.handleMessagesWithSinkSource(sink, source))
    }
  }
}
```

Chats create and pass an output-generating `Source[Message, _]` and an input-receiving `Sink[Message, _]` to `handleMessagesWithSinkSource` method.

I have a problem to create a working `source` with `Messages` populated by my `Actor` (`Source.actorRefWithBackpressure` should [allow](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/actorRefWithBackpressure.html#source-actorrefwithbackpressure) it). `Sink` and `source2` work as expected but `source` does not:

```
 def getSinkAndSource(name: String) = {
   val source = Source.actorRefWithBackpressure[Message](AckMessage, {
     case _: Success => CompletionStrategy.draining
   }, PartialFunction.empty)

   val wsActorRef = source.to(Sink.ignore).run()

   val receiver = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(classOf[ChatParticipantActor], name, ChatRoomActor, wsActorRef))
   val sink = Sink.actorRefWithBackpressure(receiver, InitMessage, AckMessage, OnCompleteMessage, onErrorMessage)

   val source2 = Source.tick(FiniteDuration(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), FiniteDuration(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), {
     implicit val writer = shared.Protocol.chatMessageRW
     TextMessage(write(ChatMessage(sender = "Bob", message = "Hi")))
   })
   (sink, source2) // This works
   (sing, source) // This does not
 }
```

How can I make such a `Source` that can be integrated with an `Akka Actor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Source.actorRef` and `Source.actorRefWithBackpressure` both create an actor that is provided as a materialized value. The server-side WS API doesn't give easy access to that materialized value, though.

The easiest way to get the actorRef that has been created is to use `mapMaterializedValue`:

```
   val source = Source.actorRefWithBackpressure[Message](AckMessage, {
     case _: Success => CompletionStrategy.draining
   }, PartialFunction.empty).mapMaterializedValue { actorRef =>
     // Do something with the ActorRef here. Messages you want to send to this client will have to be sent to this ActorRef.
     // e.g.: chatRoom ! NewClient(actorRef)
   }
```

A previous version of my chat room example was still Actor-based and shows this in a full example:

https://github.com/jrudolph/akka-http-scala-js-websocket-chat/blob/b01b234376c4984dce19effcaf001a9ffb4c6981/backend/src/main/scala/example/akkawschat/Chat.scala#L64